# Callable CoffeeScript classes

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, callable

Consider the following CoffeeScript class:

```
class Event
    trigger : (args...) =>
        ...

    bind : (args...) =>
        ...
```

The use case would be:

```
message_received = new Event()
message_received.bind(alert)                                       
message_received.trigger('Hello world!') # calls alert('Hello world')
```

Is there a way to write the `Event` class in such manner that the `.trigger(...)` call would have the "callable object" shortcut:

```
message_received('Hello world')  # ?
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return a function from the constructor, which is extended with the properties from the current instance (which in turn is inherit from `Event.prototype`).

```
class Event
    constructor : ->
        shortcut = -> shortcut.trigger(arguments...)
        for key, value of @
            shortcut[key] = value
        return shortcut

    trigger : (args...) =>
        ...

    bind : (args...) =>
        ...
```

[Compiled result](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Event%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%20%3a%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shortcut%20=%20=%3E%20shortcut.trigger%28arguments...%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20key,%20value%20of%20@%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shortcut%5Bkey%5D%20=%20value%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20shortcut%0A%0A%20%20%20%20trigger%20%3a%20=%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20bind%20%3a%20=%3E%0A)

Comment: Rob W answers a disproportionate amount of the SO issues I search for. I can only assume he's me from the future.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://gist.github.com/shesek/4636379. It allows you to write something like that:

```
Event = callable class
    trigger : (args...) =>
        ...
    bind : (args...) =>
        ...

    callable: @::trigger
```

Note: it relies on `__proto__` (no other way to set the [[Prototype]] of functions), so you shouldn't use that if you need it to work on IE. I use it for server-side code and for intranet projects when I know users won't be using IE.